# Leer texto de Captcha Utilizando Python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, captcha, ocr, pytesseract

Gente,

Vengo con la siguiente pregunta. Estoy intentando sacar el texto de imágenes Captcha, estoy utilizando Python, por el momento no consigo buen resultado, uno de 10 intentos que hace le atina, ¿me podrían ayudar, por favor, o darme recomendaciones?

[image: Esta es uno de los captcha]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código que hice, pero pues no es muy bueno la verdad.

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
import os
import numpy as np

def quitar_sombra(img):
  rgb_planes = cv2.split(img)

  result_planes = []
  result_norm_planes = []
  for plane in rgb_planes:
      dilated_img = cv2.dilate(plane, np.ones((7,7), np.uint8))
      bg_img = cv2.medianBlur(dilated_img, 21)
      diff_img = 255 - cv2.absdiff(plane, bg_img)
      norm_img = cv2.normalize(diff_img,None, alpha=0, beta=255, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, 
  dtype=cv2.CV_8UC1)
    
  result_planes.append(diff_img)
  result_norm_planes.append(norm_img)

  result = cv2.merge(result_planes)

  cv2.imwrite('captcha4.png', result)

def get_text_image():
    pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'
    #os.system("convert captcha4.jpeg -colorspace gray captcha4.jpeg")
    try:
       newImg = cv2.imread("captcha4.png")
       newImg = newImg[10:50,10:140]
       cv2.imwrite('captcha4.png',newImg)
       os.system("convert captcha4.png -negate -morphology erode octagon:2 -negate captcha4.png")
       quitar_sombra(cv2.imread("captcha4.png"))
   except Exception as _:
    return ""

   # os.system("convert captcha4.png -colorspace gray captcha4.png")
   os.system("convert captcha4.png -level 40%,100% captcha4.png")
   #os.system("convert captcha4.png -gaussian-blur 0 captcha4.png")
   #os.system("convert captcha4.png -threshold 60% captcha4.png")
   captcha:str = pytesseract.image_to_string(cv2.imread("captcha4.png"),
                            config='--psm 8 -c 
        tessedit_char_whitelist=8f2345678abcdefghkmnprwxy')
   captcha = captcha.replace(" ", "").strip()
   return captcha
```

Es más, tengo cosas comentadas de todas las pruebas que he realizado, pero nada :/, ayuda gente, pls

Comment: Utiliza una IA para eso. Es lo mejor que puedes hacer

Comment: Esos captcha fueron hechos especificamente para que un programa no pueda pasarlos. Estas tratando de hacer algo que no esta bien. Eso hara que algunos de nosotros no queramos ayudar.

Comment: Es el capchat de RUNT? estoy en las mismas para poder hacer consultas masivas, pudiste hacerlo al final?

Answer (score 0):

Lo mejor que puedes hacer es obtener el endpoint del servidor que almacena los captchas y entrenar un modelo para crear tu propio DC de captchas o puedes usar keras ocr pero debes de probar hasta calibrarlo perfectamente